# All ide from JetBrains launch extremely long on Arch Linux XFCE4

Tags: archlinux, jetbrains-ide

I have just installed fresh Arch Linux with XFCE4 and downloaded WebStorm. I did everything exactly as it is said in howto file (by executing .sh from bin folder). When i click on the WebStorm icon it looks like nothing is happening but suddenly after around 90s (and its min. value, i wonder how long it would be including project loading..) window pops up showing loading process.

I have pretty strong laptop with i7, 8gig of ram and SSD. There isn't any project loading also. It's fresh start. It used to work on Xubuntu, but it seems like i missed something during installation process or I dont know..

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use OracleJDK not OpenJDK.

And try to trace what is happening while loading from terminal because if there is any error it will appear immediately.